# Prove that $g(x)=xf(x)$ given $g$ is differentiable at $0$ and $g(0)=0$ and $f$ is some function continuous at $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

May be, I am over thinking this problem. Over here, do we just construct a piece wise function $f$ such that is $g(x)/x$ for all $x \neq 0$ and it is equal to $0$ for $x=0$?

I was a little thrown off by the question. I just didn't see a rigorous enough way to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$ and define $f(0) := \lim_{x \to 0} g(x)/x$.  To make this well-defined, show that this limit exists.  This will imply that $f$ is continuous and satisfies the necessary properties.

Comment: One question and please be charitable in answering this. Should the $f(0)$ be written as $f'(0)$? For it seems as if we use the limit def of derivatives, then we get the same expression.

Comment: @user43901: No, $f'(0)$ might not exist, and even if it does it is unlikely to equal $f(0)$.  Remembering that $g(0)=0$, what is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{g(x)}{x}$?  In particular, how do we know that limit exists from what was given in the problem?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: We should be using l'hopital's rule since the limit reaches an indeterminate state at $0/0$, taking the derivative wrt $x$ should give us $\lim_{x \to 0} g'(0)$. Since we know that  $g$ is differentiable at $0$, we can claim that the limit exists. Am I headed the right direction?

Comment: @user43901: You could do that if $g$ were assumed differentiable away from $0$, but it is not.  Even if that were given, I'm biased against it in such a case.  What is the definition of the derivative of $g$ at $0$?  I don't know what you meant by "$\lim_{x\to 0}g'(0)$", but I'm guessing based on the statement that you wanted to use l'Hôpital's rule that you meant "$g'(x)$", which is a problem because it isn't assumed to exist.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: the derivative, according to the limit definition, is $g'(0)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {g(h)}{h}$. Is that what you were getting at?

Comment: @user43901: Yes.  (Of course that is because $g(0)=0$.)  Note that if "$h$" is replaced with "$x$" it is the same limit.

Comment: So how does this definition get us out of our problem here? I am sorry, I thought this is what I mentioned in my initial comment, which I now realize I should have stated $g'(0)$. Don't we have to use L'H to actually calculate the limit, though?

Comment: @user43901:  Yes, $f(0)=g'(0)$.  This makes $f$ continuous at zero because $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)$ by the definition of $f$ and the definition of the derivative.  No, there is no l'Hôpital in sight.  The limit is $g'(0)$ by definition of $g'(0)$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I see the light now. Thank you so much for being patient.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)$ be a function which is differentiable at $0$ with $g(0)=0$. I claim that $f(x)=g(x)/x$ is continuous at $0$. It is easy to see that $f(x)$ is continuous around $0$ as the quotient of continuous functions, and we can define $f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)}{x}=g'(0)$ to make it continuous at $x=0$ by the definition of the derivative. Now, clearly $$g(x)=x\cdot\frac{g(x)}{x}=xf(x).$$

Comment: I am failing to understand what follows your "now clearly"-- would you mind hashing this out a bit for me?

Comment: By using l'Hospital's rule, you agree $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$? If so, then all I am saying is that $x\cdot g(x)/x=(x/x)\cdot g(x)=1\cdot g(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: It is not assumed in the statement of the problem that $g'(x)$ exists when $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Since $g$ is differentiable at $0$, it is not only defined around an interval around $0$, it is even continuous (and differentiable) around $0$.

Comment: @Clayton: It is true that $g$ must be defined in an interval around $0$, but it need not even be continuous, let alone differentiable, away from $0$.  For a discontinuous example, let $g(x)=x^2$ when $x$ is rational, $g(x)=0$ when $x$ is irrational.  For a continuous example, let $f(x)$ be a continuous nowhere differentiable function, and let $g(x)=xf(x)$.  On the other hand, defining $f(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{g(x)}{x}$ works by the definition of the derivative and the assumption that $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @Clayton: a follow up question-- I agree that $f$ is continuous at $0$. But is there a reason why we should define $g(x)$ in such a manner? I am trying to understand the motivation behind it. Is it just to match the form?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: You are right; my mind must have gotten away from me. Apologies to user43901, and also, yes, it is to match the form, because you want $g(x)=xf(x).$

Comment: @Clayton: why am I never satisfied with "proofs" like these? They always seem like tricks. I don't know why they always give me a weird feeling. So should we not use L'H, then?

Comment: That is correct, but notice the definition of the derivative is exactly $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=\frac{g(x)}{x}$. This gives us the continuity of $f$ at $x=0$. Also, if you ever feel uneasy about a proof, go through and justify EVERY step, breaking it down to the axioms if necessary. This will pinpoint any problems, or help you clarify what you didn't understand.